# How do I scale a large image down in HTML Canvas, for user to draw on it, then return to its ORIGINAL dimensions before saving the edits?

Tags: jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm fairly new to HTML Canvas and have a working page that has a 5 MP image shown in a 600x400 canvas, where you can draw on it. But the problem is after the edits are made, when I submit the image back to the server, it's sending the scaled-down version of the image which is saved.

I am getting the image data back out by using:
`$("#hiddenimage").val(canvas.toDataURL());`
Where hiddenimage is a hidden variable.

I want the edits applied to the full-size image and saved but shown to the user in a canvas of a reasonable size. This seems like it should be an easy thing to do and obvious, but nothing I've tried is working.

Comment: One option is to make the canvas the same size as image, and scale it to 600x400 using css when user draws on it

Comment: Yep! Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks, that works.

Now the drawings/edits are only being applied to the smaller canvas size, so just need to figure out what's causing that.  Thank you.

Comment: You can also look into `save` and `restore` functions on the canvas context